# StackOverflowException occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

My project was working fine, but I'm having this weird error for some time while trying to print or even show report. Sometimes it works fine, but when I try to print this report multiple times like more than 50 or something it throws this error. I've spent weeks trying to figure out the solution. I've checked multiple times there's no recursive loop and now I'm just pulling my hairs. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Initialized at Form_Load:

```
ReportDocument cryRptEdu = new ReportDocument();
TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfosEdu = new TableLogOnInfos();
TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfoEdu = new TableLogOnInfo();
ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfoEdu = new ConnectionInfo();

try
{
    cryRptEdu.Load(rptpathEdu);
}
catch (Exception x)
{
    KryptonMessageBox.Show(x.Message, "Error Occured", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
}

crConnectionInfoEdu.ServerName = Program.serverName;
crConnectionInfoEdu.DatabaseName = Program.dbName;
crConnectionInfoEdu.UserID = Program.saName;
crConnectionInfoEdu.Password = Program.pw;
Tables CrTables = cryRptEdu.Database.Tables;
foreach (Table CrTable in CrTables)
{
    crtableLogoninfoEdu = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
    crtableLogoninfoEdu.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfoEdu;
    CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfoEdu);
}
```

On Print Button:

```
cryRptEdu.SetParameterValue("percentage", percentage);
cryRptEdu.SetParameterValue("grades", grade);
cryRptEdu.SetParameterValue("position", position);
cryRptEdu.SetParameterValue("attendance", attendance);
cryRptEdu.SetParameterValue("midTermPercentage", midTermPercentage);
cryRptEdu.SetParameterValue("finalPercentage", finalPercentage);
cryRptEdu.SetParameterValue("aggregatePercentage", aggregatePercentage);
cryRptEdu.SetParameterValue("midTermGrade", midTermGrade);
cryRptEdu.SetParameterValue("finalGrade", finalGrade);
cryRptEdu.SetParameterValue("aggrgateGrade", aggregateGrade);
cryRptEdu.SetParameterValue("tl1", tl1);
cryRptEdu.SetParameterValue("tl2", tl2);
cryRptEdu.SetParameterValue("pl1", pl1);
cryRptEdu.SetParameterValue("pl2", pl2);
if (print)
    cryRptEdu.PrintToPrinter(1, true, 1, 1);
else
    cryRptEdu.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, exportPath + ID + ".pdf");
```

While Printing:

[image]

[image]

Stack trace:

[image]

Comment: What is your code doing. Post some logic following with code. Not just a few pictures of where the error occurs.

Comment: What's the stack trace when you get the exception?

Comment: Updated, please check.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolved the issue using backgroundworker.